# "this" keyword meaning in Android

Tags: android, constructor, this

I am a beginner in Android Development. The `this` keyword always makes me confused when used in any constructor. Can someone please explain to me what does it mean?

```
RelativeLayout ob = new RelativeLayout(this);
Button btn = new Button(this);
```

What does `this` mean in the previous constructors? What is it referring to?

Comment: **this** refers to the current class you are in. The view constructor requires you to provide a context and the only nearest context you have is **this** which is the current class.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#RelativeLayout(android.content.Context)), the `RelativeLayout` constructor takes in an instance of `Context`. I am assuming you are calling that code in an activity, probably in the `onStart` method. If this is the case, the `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the activity. In android, Activities extend the `ContextWrapper` class, making them a subclass of the Context class and therefore passable to the `RelativeLayout` and `Button` constructor.

The `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the class that holds the method containing the constructor that you are calling.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the instance of class that this is code is in so for example:

```
public class Foo {
    private string bar = "bar";

    public Foo(string bar)
    {
        this.bar // <-- refers to global bar. Not the bar from constructor.
    }
}
```

In your case `this` requires to by of type of the parameter that `RelativeLayout` requires, so your class probably must be extended by something that `RelativeLayout` requires.